# How to build a tree sideways and downwards?

Tags: haskell, tree

How can I build a tree downwards and horizontally?

I current have a tree:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

Then, I have a root `Int` and list of `[Int]`

```
1 and [2,3,4]
```

I want to build a tree like

```
       1
    /  |  \
   2   3   4
  /\  / \  /\
 3  4 2 4 2  3
 |  | | | |  |
 4  3 4 2 3  2
```

In Haskell, it looks like

```
Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [Node 4 []],Node 4[Node 3 []]], Node 3 [Node 2 [Node 4 []], 
Node 4 [Node 2 []]], Node 4 [Node 2 [Node 3 []], Node 3 [Node 2 []]]]
```

Here's what I've tried:
This code grows my tree downwards

```
down :: Int -> [Int] -> Tree Int
down y [] = Node y []
down y (x:xs) = Node y [down x xs]
```

This code grows my tree sideways

```
side :: Int -> [Int] -> Tree Int
side y [] = Node y []
side y x = Node y $ map (\x -> Node x []) y
```

Now, I'm having trouble piecing it together to get the solution above. Any help is appreciated

Comment: So, every path in the tree is just a permutation of `[1,2,3,4]` that starts with `1`?

Comment: @chepner yeah, that's right

Comment: What's the trouble you're having?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I'm not sure how to piece the code that grows the tree downwards and sideways together to get the tree that I want

Comment: The tricky part is that doing this isn't simply a composition of the two techniques. The list of integers available to choose from at each level changes from branch to branch.

Comment: @chepner oh. do you have any ideas on how I can approach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can introduce a helper function `pick` that will generate a list of 2-tuples with the item we picked, and return the remaining list. We can implement this with a difference list, but a simple, less efficient implementation is:

```
import Data.List(tails, inits)

pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick vs = [(x, ws ++ xs) | (ws, (x:xs)) <- zip (inits vs) (tails vs) ]
```

Then we thus retrieve:

```
Prelude Data.List> pick [2,3,4]
[(2,[3,4]),(3,[2,4]),(4,[2,3])]
```

Now we can change your `down` function:

```
down :: a -> [a] -> Tree a
down y = Node y . map (uncurry down) . pick
```

For the given sample data, we then get:

```
Prelude Data.List> down 1 [2,3,4]
Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [Node 4 []],Node 4 [Node 3 []]],Node 3 [Node 2 [Node 4 []],Node 4 [Node 2 []]],Node 4 [Node 2 [Node 3 []],Node 3 [Node 2 []]]]
```